# Need to develop a PHP - Jabber based chat

Tags: php, jquery, xmpp, chat

I was trying to develop a web based chat system using PHP. I created one with the combination of jQuery and PHP but this setup is using lot of network bandwidth as it is continuously sending / receiving data to check whether a new message has been received or not (currently every 1 second). So I need to develop a system that will automatically display the message once a message is received from the other end without the need of sending a request to the server to see if there is a new message received.

I read in many places that this can be done using Jabber. I am really new to this jabber technology, so any help creating a new Jabber based chat using PHP will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for specific questions, not vague advice.  Try to do something yourself and then come back if you run into specific problems.

Comment: Research **long polling**. This can be tricky, and may require you to learn Node.js to control this feature, but will drastically reduce bandwidth usage.

Comment: @Corbin Thanks! I am working on it.. will let you know the specific problem if i face any.

Comment: I'm a big fan of web sockets. I've used it for a nice chat client and some other web apps myself.

Comment: @cillosis Thanks! I am looking into your suggestion..

Answer (score -1):

Jabber (also known as XMPP) is more of a protocol, so it's not really the solution you're looking for.

HTML 5 web sockets are a great new technology to achieve this. Rather than polling to see if there are any messages, the server can "push" new messages to the browser.

The client side code is JavaScript. The server side can be anything implementing the web socket protocol. There are probably some PHP libraries to write the server side code, but I have written a few Ruby web socket servers using EventMachine and em-websocket.